# Non-GPL alternative to db4o

Tags: android, db4o

I'm developing a closed source Android application. I was using db4o to persist data on the device and I found it very easy and straightforward to use. 
Unfortunately I didn't get informed about it's license which is GPL until now. 
As far as I understood it, by using db4o in my app I would have to make it open source, which I can't do. 
What would be the easiest, most painless replacement for db4o under a less restictive license (Apache)?

Answer (score 0):

Try [OrmLIte](http://ormlite.com/) . It has [Android support](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml), works fine and the API is relatively friendly. It uses the [ISC license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISC_license), similar to BSD.

Also, note that db40 has a [commercial license as well](http://db4o.com/commercial/), if that's an option.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask what you mean by 'relatively'?

Comment: Heh, I thought I should edit that to clarify :). There are no bugs or anything like that, I meant specifically the "friendliness" of the API - by "relatively" here I meant that you have to spend some time to learn the ropes, especially for N-M mappings, but the learning curve is comparable to other frameworks.